# Word for method that gets and sets?

Tags: api, naming

Is there a word for the API pattern where a method may get or set, depending on whether it is called with an argument or none?

This style is often used in JavaScript:

```
obj.prop();                // Returns value
obj.prop(new_value);       // Sets new value
```

A variation for dictionary-like properties takes one or two arguments respectively:

```
obj.dict(key);             // Returns value for key
obj.dict(key, new_value);  // Sets new value for key
```

Again, does this style have a name?

**EDIT**: The word *proxy* doesn't seem half bad to me. Any devastating arguments against calling these kind of functions *proxies*?

Comment: I call it an accessor method, but in the end there's no right answer. I'm therefore voting to close this question as “primarily opinion-based”.

Comment: That isn't one method, it's two different methods, they're just related by overloading. The generic term is *accessor*, but each of these methods is still a getter or a setter, not just an accessor.

Comment: Accessor-mutator and getter-setter – these are word pairs that are used in less dynamic languages. I'm looking for a single word. I guess "accessor" is the more generic one...

Comment: I don't think it's viable using the term "overloading" in the context of JavaScript.

Comment: Both. When a concept is given a name, it becomes easier to talk about – and to research further, not least. Normally I would name these functions after what they get/set – something like `miffy.diet(food)` – but right now I'm doing a bit of meta-programming.

Comment: Would it be completely insane calling that kind of function a "proxy", maybe?

Comment: @dalgard Proxy is used for a different concept (see [Proxy pattern on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)), so that wouldd be very confusing. *Accessor* is decent choice.

Comment: The first in each of your example sets is generally referred to as an accessor method. The latter a mutator. If the language supports accessing them as if they were fields/member variables, then they are generally referred to as properties. In all cases though, they offer a false sense of encapsulation, so all of them can be referred to as "poor man's encapsulation".

Comment: @DavidArno: If the accessor only gets/sets variables that aren't themselves properties, but only exist in the accessor's closure, I'd say it is a form of encapsulation that is fully equal to private properties in other languages?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The concept I'm referring to is not an OOP pattern, but rather an API style. Words mean different things in different contexts – wouldn't you say we are far enough removed from the OOP concept of a proxy for it to be fair use?

Comment: To answer this question without being primarily opinion based, one should look into authoritative references on the subject, and see if they have coined/suggested an appropriate term.